# Какой у вас жизненный цикл задач от постановки до релиза?

Tags: веб-программирование, jira, scrum, release-management, менеджмент

В процессе жизненного цикла задачи, от постановки до релиза, у нас возникают некоторые сложности.
Вопрос как в менеджерам, там и к разработчикам)

Жизненный цикл:

1. Надо сделать
2. В работе
3. Тестирование (после того, как разработчик выполнил задачу, переводит ее сюда, и ставит ответственным Тестировщика)
4. В релиз (Тестировщики переводят сюда протестированные задачи, и ставят ответственного за релизы)
5. Готово

Сложности именно в процессе перехода задачи из Тестирования в Релиз.
Дело в том, что за релиз отвечают отдельные сотрудник, и как только у них появляется задача, они сразу пускают в релиз.
А тестировщики не всегда понимают, что нельзя не каждую задачу можно сразу пускать В релиз (просто забирают ветку из GitHub), после Тестирования.
Т.е. для некоторых задачи может быть необходимо запуск миграций и прочих системных задач, без который после Релиза продашн сломается.

Я предлагал, чтобы тестировщики, после тестирования переводили задачу обратно на разработчика, чтобы потом разработчик сам перенес ее в Релиз, и оставил необходимые комментарии (для запуска миграций и прочего) для специалистов, которые выпускают релиз.
Но менеджеры говорят, что так нельзя из-за каких-то менеджерских процессов..

Интересно, как у других выстроен этот процесс  и решаются подобные ситуации?

Comment: Stack Overflow не для опросов.

Comment: @andreymal дожились, на SO нельзя уже задать вопрос по процессам разработки. только про парсинг html регексами можно!

Comment: @PashaPash конечно же можно, если это не опрос

Comment: @andreymal это не опрос, в тексте есть конкретная проблема, для которой автор хочет решения.

Comment: @andreymal "как решить подобную ситуацию" == "как исправить эту ошибку". почему про код такое можно задавать, а про процессы - нельзя?

Comment: @PashaPash «Какой у вас жизненный цикл» и «как у других выстроен этот процесс» — это очевиднейший опрос. (Вы уже второй за сутки, отрицающий очевидное, что происходит с людьми?)

Comment: @PashaPash задавать вопросы про процессы конечно же можно, **если это не опросы**

Comment: @andreymal а описание ситуациии и "как ... решаются подобные ситуации" - очевиднейший не-опрос, на который можно дать конкретный объективный ответ. странно что вы уже не первый человек за сутки, не дочитывающий вопрос до конца перед тем, как нажать "закрыть" %))

Comment: @PashaPash а почему вы не хотите дочитывать вопрос до конца и игнорируете существование очевидно опросных частей «какой у вас» и «как у других»? Пока эти части присутствуют в тексте вопроса — он должен быть закрыт.

Comment: @andreymal ну а я думаю что не должен. на мету? :))

Comment: @PashaPash какой смысл на мету, просто автору стоит удалить очевидно опросные части и я отзову свой голос за закрытие

Comment: @andreymal ужас. сколько шума из-за "лишних частей". хороший же интересный вопрос.

Comment: @PashaPash в текущем виде — всё ещё опрос. У нас здесь не разговоры по душам, а строго оформленная база знаний, поэтому я как добропорядочный пользователь считаю своим долгом разводить шум во благо базы знаний.

Answer (score 0):

Сами пункты у всех, скорее всего, будут более-менее одинаковыми - т.к. у вас перечислены статусы задачи. У нас, например, ревью есть между "в работе" и "тестированием" но это локальные проблемы.

У вас явно проблема в процессе, и если стадии заданы жестко, новые статусы вводить нельзя, назад по статусам перемещать нельзя, то решение у вас только одно - разработчики должны расписывать миграции и прочее, важное для релиза, до отдачи задачи тестировщикам.

Ну или убирать людей, которые занимаются ручным релизом и полностью автоматизировать процесс. Мы убрали, у нас релиз по мержу в мастер, и процесс выглядит так:

1. Code
2. Открытие пулла с метками "ждет подтверждения на тест", и "не тестировано". Если пулл требует миграций базы - то еще и "нужна миграция"
3. Review (через PR в гитхабе). Ревьювер также вычитвает задачу на тестирование. Снимает метку "ждет подтверждения на тест" с пулла.
4. Test. QA снимает метку "не тестирован" по результатам.
5. Если есть метка "требует миграций" - генерируются миграции, если для них нужно тестирование - проводят отдельным пуллом.
6. Любой пулл с "протестировано" и без "требует миграций" можно мержить.
7. По мержу в мастер улетает в продакшн.

Comment: спасибо большое!

`назад по статусам перемещать нельзя `
именно поэтому менеджеры не дают вариант, который я предлагал.

Пока есть сложности с вводом CI/CD, процесс не быстрый.

`разработчики должны расписывать миграции и прочее, важное для релиза, до отдачи задачи тестировщикам.`
наши менеджеры тоже так предлагают, но когда задача идет в Тестирование, это еще не конечное решение. Как минимум работа может быть сделана не правильно, или могут быть какие-то доп. уточнения (как обычно и бывает). 
Поэтому мне кажется, что заранее писать миграции - это лишнее.

Comment: @samiy-slavniy-maliys тогда вводите статус или метку "нужна миграция" и обучайте тестировщиков и команду деплоя. это явно не техническая проблема :)